# Prove that $\wedge$ and $\sim$ is an adequate set of connectives.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

below is my answer to the question:

To prove that $\wedge$ and $\sim$ is an adequate set of connectives, we need to show that $\vee$ and $\Longrightarrow$ is definable in terms of $\wedge$ and $\sim$.

I can prove that $\sim$ (P $\Longrightarrow$ Q) $\equiv$ P $\wedge$ $\sim$ Q.

According to DeMorgan's Laws:
$\sim$ (P $\vee$ Q) $\equiv$ $\sim$ P $\wedge$ $\sim$ Q

Therefore, the work of the connectives $\wedge$, $\Longrightarrow$, $\vee$ and $\sim$ can be done by $\wedge$ and $\sim$ alone.

Does the above explanation satisfy the question? How do you approach this? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you already know an adequate set of connectives, then you only have to show that all of those can be defined in terms of the proposed new adequate set.  If not, you will need to show that all $2^4 = 16$ possible two-argument connectives can be expressed in terms of the new adequate set.

Comment: No adequate set of connectives was provided. So you meant I need to use an example like $2^4 = 16$ to prove that?

Comment: You need to write down the 16 possible truth tables for P,Q and show that they all can be expressed in terms of $\wedge$ and $\sim$.

Comment: @GEdgar oh, gotcha. I need to prove the equivalences of those pairs of truth table. It seems quite a tedious approach. Do you have any other shorter or simpler way to prove that?